# What if a body has no force acting on it?

Tags: forces

What body will do if force is not there? Is there any body which has no force? I am not talking about zero net force.

Comment: Could you please clarify? What do you mean by "a body which has no force?" And how is this different from zero net force?

Comment: @AaronStevens You can have forces acting on a body without a net force, no?

Comment: @BobD Yes. But that is not what the OP seems to be saying. They seem to be saying that having no forces acting on an object at all would not mean a zero net force. To me saying no forces are acting on a body means we are also talking about zero net force. The OP seems to think this is not true. Hence my request for clarification.

Comment: Have you learned Newton’s First Law?

Answer (score 1):

> What body will do if force is not there?

Well, we know it won't undergo acceleration (Newton's second law). But it could undergo constant velocity (Newton's first law). For that matter the body may do neither. For example:

I am pushing on a wall. It pushes back on me with an equal and opposite force  (Newton's third law). The wall is imbedded in the earth which opposes the force I apply to the wall. Static friction between my feet and the ground opposes the force the wall exerts on me. Neither I nor the wall are subjected to a net force and neither moves.

> Is there any body which has no force?

No body in the universe is free from gravitational forces.

Hope this helps.